# As a course lecturer, should I excuse late assignment submissions if I wrote the assignment deadline slightly wrong?

Tags: teaching, coursework

I am the course lecturer of an undergraduate course.
For a recent assignment, I had written the assignment deadline as 23 November 2018 (Saturday). Unfortunately, 23 November is actually a **Friday**, and not a **Saturday**.

I received an email from a student asking for me to excuse his/her assignment which was submitted late. The student explained that he/she marked the deadline as Saturday, without checking the assignment date.

#### Question

*Should I excuse the student's late submission because I made a slight mistake in specifying the assignment deadline?*

Note: We use a learning management system to receive assignment submissions, and the assignment deadline was entered correctly in the learning management system.

#### What I decided to do

**For the current incident:**
After reading the answers, and thinking it through, I decided that it is better to use the later of the two deadlines (i.e., 24 November Saturday) as the official deadline for the assignment.
I did make a mistake in writing the wrong day of the week for the deadline,
and students could have been misled with my mistake.
It is not fair to punish such students for my mistake.

**For future courses:**

- The more places I put the deadline in
  (e.g., the syllabus, the assignment itself, the learning management system),
  it becomes likely that I will make a mistake somewhere.
- In the future, I will put the deadline in only the learning management system, and refer students to check the deadlines there.

Comment: _In dubio pro reo_…

Comment: What would be the benefits for you or for your students of rejecting this single assignment which was submitted on Saturday? (I can't see a compelling benefit.)

Comment: @ebosi: There's also a legal doctrine called [*contra proferentem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra_proferentem) that seems on point here.

Comment: In addition to the reasons given by answers, to stick to the shorter deadline you will need to argue that such a small error doesn't matter, and that could backfire in a few days when you grade their assignments and some perceivedly small mistakes will need to matter.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You're right, that's more accurate indeed. Thanks for improving.

Comment: BTW how do you accidentally name a weekend day if you don’t want that? (That thinking can also be applied by your students)

Comment: I can’t figure out a reason why I ***wouldn’t*** accept the homework as on-time in this case. To err is human, to say “mea culpa” is divine.

Comment: @eckes Maybe the syllabus from last year was reused, but the dates were being changed, and this one slipped through the cracks? That happened to one of my professors a couple years ago (he caught it before it caused any issues like this question, but it shows that it happens nonetheless)

Comment: Wow, all these answers. I would like to answer with a question: what is best for your students? The mistake was clearly yours (teacher) and not theirs (students)....

Comment: Yet another reason to put dates on assignments in the course management system and in the syllabus, etc state "refer to online course resources for due dates".  If the assignment was submitted on (Saturday) I would accept it.

Comment: I know this question has already been thoroughly answered, but I just wanted to mention that the fact that the date is correct in the homework submission system does not at all change anything.  I often don't even look at my homework until the day before it's due, and since the student was told it was due on Saturday (I don't look at the date, I look at the day of the week), it's completely realistic that the student didn't even look at the homework submission site until Saturday

Comment: For future homework assignments, consider having a teaching assistant go over the assignment before it's published, to see if there aren't any "cognitive blind spots" which a second pair of eyes is more likely to notice.

Comment: Does your university have any policies on the subject? I know that when I was going to university, one of the units I took had two different dates published for the due date of one of the assignments, and he had to go with one of them over the other due to the university's policies.

Comment: Quick note here: If you don't accept it late, you're saying that you can make a mistake but your students can't, which is a bad precedent to set because they'll no longer trust you.

Comment: I'm surprised this question would even be posted. Do you really think it could possibly be okay to deny a student turning in an assignment late because *you* made an ambiguous statement about the due date? Seriously? You are in the business of education (at least partially), not intellectual warfare. The students are not the enemy.

Comment: For perspective; your situation is vastly different as no one has likely been inconvenienced all that much BUT as a student one of my lecturers gave incorrect deadlines on a couple of occasions.  One in particular, with a time difference of a full week, still vexes me to this day.  Some students got the extra week and therefore had more time for work on other modules (hand-ins were supposed to be staggered), while others had to slog like mad to meet the incorrect deadline and work for other modules suffered as a result.  Mayou36 is correct, but don't expect other students to like it.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

First thing: The student **handed in on the *shown* deadline**. That says *everything*. Not accepting is not an option in any reasonable way. But to be more specific:

**In dubio pro reo** *(in a case where nothing happened anyway)*

Mistakes happen. Like you writing the wrong day for a certain date. Happened once, the "damage" is that students *may* have a reason to hand in *one day later*. That's it. And that's basically nothing.

Students are humans too. Most probably he/she really did not pay too much attention, did not look it up properly. Like no one of us would have or normally does in his daily business. And that's fine. Because it was not about life and death.

Let it be like that and accept the hand-in saying that you really wrote the wrong day (and may even apologize for the small mistake, as it may caused some confusion and a little anxiety to the student when he realized it). Even thinking about that incident is too much energy wasted for nothing happened. And be happy that you did not write the date of a test wrong or similar. Keep the mouse a mouse, don't make it an elephant.

*Also, not accepting it will result in punishing a (most probably) innocent student. That's just unfair and will leave a very bad impression with the student. No reason to risk that.*

.

Comment: Clearing comments because that issue seems to be resolved now to everybody’s satisfaction.

Answer (score 171):

If the assignment deadline was not shown correctly to the students, then it is **your** error and they cannot be penalized for being late.

Claiming it is correct in one area while incorrect in another does not absolve you, you caused the confusion so you have to accept late submissions, as long as they arrived on Saturday...

Any submissions on Sunday will, of course, be late.

Re-reading this, it sounds a bit blunt... Probably because I have done exactly the same and had to sort it out after... Peace reigns if you stick to being fair, so giving them the extra time does not usually make much of a difference, except for the recognition from the students.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86611/discussion-on-answer-by-solar-mike-as-a-course-lecturer-should-i-excuse-late-as).

Answer (score 99):

If you occasionally published two different dates as a deadline, you should accept the work until the latest date without penalty. This is what essentially happened: you announced the deadline as 23rd Nov 2018 but also as Saturday, which is not the same day. Go with the latest of two then — this is the best way to be fair in this situation.

Comment: Yup. Not least because if they appeal it, a) it'll waste your time having to explain that you're an incompetent and b) the university will likely side with the student and you'll look bad.

Comment: Kinda off-topic, but one of my instructors once mistakenly wrote the deadline as 11/27/2108, and we still got penalties for submitting after 11/27/2018 :(

Comment: @nalzok: A hundred years is far too much extra time for school work.

Comment: @user21820 Arguable :)

Comment: @user21820 some students would still be late after having 100 years :) ...

Comment: @nalzok Worth that being pointed out in the answer though - that "latest" date in this case doesn't (hopefully) affect OPs marking schedule. Whereas 100 years in the future (or even a week) definitely would - which is worth considering when deciding how much leniency to give.

Comment: @user21820 there are only 90 years between 2018 and 2108...

Comment: @CactusCake: I suppose you think that Fermat considers Wiles his student. =)

Answer (score 54):

I think the most important question a teacher should ask about their own actions is "What my action will teach?"

If you accept the late submission you will teach that one must assume their own mistakes and get full responsibility.

If you don't, you will teach that the people with more power don't need to clean up and take responsibility after mistakes, and the underdogs should not trust them.

We can say the last will prepare the student to be a good employee in the corporate world, and the first to be a responsible person.

Comment: Very good point regarding setting a personal example! Teachers educate students as persons, they don't just teach particular subject matter. +1

Comment: While I agree with the idea of the teaching, being strict with with the date does not teach that "people with power don't need to clean up...", but that it is the student's responsability to make sure to have all the elements in hand. I'm still in favour of a lenient response, but the second part of your answer is biased.

Comment: Maybe my answer is biased, but I think I don't need to "make sure" I "have all the elements in hand" if I trust my superior. If the student is penalized because they don't catch the professor mistake, we are not teaching students to be attentive, but that "s*** goes down", and we must not trust our superiors. The result would be improved attention? Sure. but the message was not "Attention is important".

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin really, it is the student’s responsibility to always be on their guard in case against incompetence or errors on the side of their instructors? That seems unreasonable. If we required such hyper-vigilance from students, they would not have any time left for studying.

Comment: Well I disagree, Students aren't Kindergarten kids. They can take care of themselves and do not need to be taken by hand every time. By your logic, the student could deliver any saturday, that would have been ok. I disagree. There were an error in the requirement, the student should be able to spot it. Why assume Saturday was fine and not the date? Again, I don't think that student should be penalised here. But I still disagree with your second part.

Comment: The latter would prepare people for the corporate world, but would reinforce bad ethics in that corporate world by punishing students into accepting those bad virtues. Could you plz edit to either agree or disagree with this, even one or two words to make it clear.

Answer (score 22):

Purely from a standpoint of error distance, I would probably put more trust in the spelled-out day than in a numeric date, if there's any conflict between the two, because it's much more likely to accidentally hit `3` instead of `4` than to type `Satur` when you meant to type `Fri`. Of course that only applies to the mechanical aspect of typing, for most brains it's probably just as easy to mix the two up.

In any case, unless you noticed your error and communicated an unambiguous correction within a reasonable timeframe, it seems only fair that you should accept submissions up to the latest possible reasonable interpretation of the originally communicated deadline.

I say “reasonable" interpretation, because I guess the *latest possible* interpretation would be Saturday, November 23rd of the next year in which November 23rd is a Saturday. (This wouldn’t make sense in an academic context, but it’s a possible result of a typo in some longer-range planning.)

Answer (score 13):

#### You can only hold people to what you *said clearly*, not to what you *intended*

> I did make a mistake in writing the wrong day of the week for the deadline

Says you. As a student, I was given an assignment due on Saturday the 24th. What's that you're saying? That the numeric date has 23 rather than 24? Oh, surely that's the mistaken - it's just a typo.

See what I mean?

Actually, even in a more extreme case, where you merely hinted that the later day is appropriate, and did not spell it out, you should still have accepted late submissions.

Comment: This looks more like a comment to a [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/120926/as-a-course-lecturer-should-i-excuse-late-assignment-submissions-if-i-wrote-the#comment320332_120927), except for the bolded line that actually adresses the OP.

Comment: I guess I don't see what you mean, if all you've done here is swap one ambiguous date for another. And my point was the date was given twice, once nonsensically, which cannot be followed as the day didn't exist in the current year, and one _clearly_, where it was online. Just like you want.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm: Which date in your opinion was the sensical one, and which the non-sensical one?

Comment: @einpoklumthe nonsensical one is "saturday, Nov. 23". The "sensical"  one is the date on the online system which presumably was "nov. 23". Those are not three dates they are two. As a student you are held responsible for _everything_ you are told, not your favorite piece of information.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm: [That's just, like, your opinion, man.](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/thats-just-like-your-opinion-man). I saw a perfectly sensical date and a typo, and that's a reasonable - even if not the only interpretation. The fact that it says something else on the online system doesn't change anything, because once I saw that Saturday, I was reading the submission date information anywhere else - I already knew when I needed to submit.

Comment: Why are you responding to a comment to a different answer in your answer?  It dilutes the point you're trying to make.

Comment: @Beska: I'm not sure what you mean. I responded to comments on my answer.

Comment: @einpoklum You did not see a typo, you made a self-serving assumption. Good students will be careful to interpret the situation in the safest way and use the earliest date. You think you're being clever but you just look like another slacker, depressing us about our career choice in teaching. If a military junta took over your vacation spot and told you to leave the country by saturday the 23rd or be shot, I'd expect you'd be out by the 23rd, not saturday.

Comment: @einpoklum Beska is referring to your quoted text.  That is a comment on Solar Mike's answer by someone who is not the OP.  I'm also confused as to why you posted a response to a comment on another answer as an answer.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm: You can't presume to know what I perceive and why. Also, while  my assumption may be self-serving, but it could be subconscious, so that effectively the only thing I know is the result of that assumption. "Good students will be careful" - some will, some will get mixed up. About the military junta example, [this](https://youtu.be/aNaXdLWt17A?t=110) is what will more likely to happen.

Comment: @einpoklum Yet you presumed to know why the instructor wrote the 23rd.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm: I was reflecting what a student may assume (rather than presume) was the case.

Comment: @kuhl: Oh, sorry, yes, I had somehow attributed that comment to OP (and now it's gone anyway). See edit.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, there seem to be (at least) two different kinds of professors/teachers: those who believe that it is their purpose to convey knowledge and those who believe it is their purpose to fail students. At this point, I'm making to judgement here; it is easy to find ethical and rational reasoning for both approaches (i.e. the '[high washout rate](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100630184621AAipBxr)' used in some colleges) but I will leave judging the ethics of those as an exercise for the reader.

So—you probably want to ask yourself what your purpose in teaching is.

Is it to teach students, proliferate knowledge, and make sure people learn what you want to course to convey? If so, be lenient.

If, on the other hand, you think your principal job is to filter students by failing them hard and early, this is a perfect opportunity to do so.

Comment: could you please clarifythat you are *not* being sarcastic to make your point, or edit it to make your point without sarcasm. You seem a little new and sarcasm is usually not accepted on SO. Not downvoting, just trying to br helpful.

Comment: @JesseSteele Like so? Or am I still coming across as sarcastic?

Comment: On the contrary, I'd say there are two kinds of students, those who are there to learn, and those who are allergic to effort. Professors, depending on where they are, and how much it bothers them to be lied to, _lied about_, etc., will have very different experiences teaching and will develop different kinds of standards for their classrooms.

Comment: "allergic to effort" that made me smile...

Comment: @Bex, what you added made tons of sense to me and I know exactly what you mean. So, I edited it to make it a little more clear and used terms that convey your point. One example I know of is the Cooley law school in Michigan that actually uses that, but I didn't want to get specific in the post. You really do have an objective idea here, it defends a lot of professors, saves students grief later on, and I hope this helps people see that in your post. Thanks for doing this and sticking to it!

Comment: @JesseSteele Thank you for your understanding and for your edit.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm I don't see how your statement in any way contradicts mine. It's no secret there are a hordes of sloppy and lazy students. But there are also a lot of sloppy professors. What really surprises me is that sloppy professors hold their students to higher standards than they do their selves.

Comment: @Bex It contradicts yours because it provides an alternative explanation besides your "sloppy" theory. The professors are being strict because they believe it is the best way to control students. The ultimate goal of that control is making them learn (despite their best efforts not to). As for higher standards, the symmetry you desire is misguided. The student is there to be taught, and be rated on how well they performed. The prof is there to do a job for a salary according to a contract. These are not comparable.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm They bloody well are comparable.  A student can be good (professional, passion for learning, happy to slog, willing to help others, etc.) or bad (unprofessional, doesn't care, lazy, selfish, etc.).  A lecturer/professor can be good (professional, passion for learning, happy to slog, willing to help others, etc.) or bad (unprofessional, doesn't care, lazy, selfish, etc.).  Giving "an alternative explanation", in this case, doesn't directly contradict the point in question.  It just outlines your bias regarding who's fault it is when a student doesn't do well absent context.

Comment: @BrentHackers No they are not comparable. And your little counter isn't even a comparison, you have just assigned similar adjectives to people in two completely different roles. My dog can be lazy and unprofessional too. That doesn't say squat about anything. And speaking of bias, you are the one all triggered and ranting.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm Didn't mean that to come across as a rant.  It read to me that you believe your argument that students can be lazy somehow contradicts the point above.  And I would argue that both lazy teachers and lazy learners can quite easily co-exist.  And, for the record, I could compare some of both my peers and lecturers from my Uni days to lazy dogs.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no other choice for you than to excuse your student. As he/ she already mentioned that he/ she follow calendar day deadline instead of  calendar date  which is also clearly mentioned in your submission deadline . So being a very valid reason and a typo mistake on your part, your student should be given excuse .

Comment: The student doesn't need to be excused, because he/she **was not late**.  The deadline was "Saturday", the work was turned in before the deadline.  There is nothing to excuse.